# How to get filename to activated application within applescript?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, automation, applescript

I am creating an applescript that opens terminal, I am dragging a file onto the script (using automater) and want the directory/name of file to be fed into my terminal application

```
    on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script with command "qpdf --qdf arg1 output.pdf"
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: The only part I'm not quite understanding about your question is "I am dragging a file onto the script (using automater[sic])". Do you mean you want to make a script application that accepts dropped items, or are you just concerned with passing arguments to `on run` ?

Comment: yes, ultimately I am just trying to create a batch file that handles arguments... I don't understand how to do this, I am using automater to create a apple script, clicking export so that it makes a little program, then I am dragging a file onto the 'program'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Automator. Save this script as an application instead...

```
    on open of droppedItems
    tell application "Terminal"
        if not (exists window 1) then reopen
        activate
    end tell

    repeat with anItem in droppedItems
        set itemPath to POSIX path of anItem
        tell application "Terminal"
            do script "qpdf --qdf " & quoted form of itemPath & " output.pdf" in window 1
            -- do script "echo " & quoted form of itemPath in window 1
        end tell
    end repeat
end open
```

Comment: confused how i put my 'arg1' in place .... so it turns into this? 
on open of droppedItems
    repeat with anItem in droppedItems
        set itemPath to POSIX path of anItem
        tell application "Terminal"
            activate
            do script with command "echo qpdf --qdf output.pdf" & quoted form of itemPath
        end tell
    end repeat
end open

Comment: I just used echo as an example of a terminal command with a path in it. quoted form of itemPath can be used to pass the path into the command properly.